# MailKit steam content to string variable C#

Tags: c#, steam, mailkit

I'm using MailKit library with C# to read some emails that contain attachment (xml files); so far i'm able to get the email with the attachement and write it to disk.

```
using (var stream = File.Create(part.FileName))
 part.Content.DecodeTo(stream);
```

then i was going to read the file and store it into a table. but where the  program will be execute will not have grant access to write/read to disk.

how can i redirect the stream content to a string variable after it is Decode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to a `MemoryStream`, then decode the string afterwards:

```cs
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
part.Content.DecodeTo(stream);
// Assuming it's UTF-8...
string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.Length);
```

Comment: thank. you point me to the right path. that is how my code end:  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                part.Content.DecodeTo(stream);
                                mailContainer.xmlContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.GetBuffer());
                            }

Comment: @PIBA: That's *incorrect* code. The buffer in a `MemoryStream` is typically larger than the current length, to avoid reallocating on every write. I very deliberately used the overload of `GetString` accepting the offset and length - you should do that.